# RSA: Is padding necessary for key exchange?

Tags: rsa, key-exchange

When RSA is strictly used to exchange random shared secrets, is the padding scheme important for security or can it be omitted entirely?

The party in possession of an RSA public key will generate entropy for a symmetric key, encrypt it with the RSA public key and send it off. After that point any failure will only be known through AEAD rejection.

Lets stipulate that the entropy bit string is of the same magnitude as the RSA modulus, or some number such that m^e >> n.

In such a scenario is textbook RSA actually safe?

Comment: You have rediscovered the RSA-KEM. It hasn't seen much use due to the existence of DH.

Comment: See: [Security of RSA-KEM against cube root attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/74280/18298) and [Where is RSA-KEM used as of 2020?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/83470/18298)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The principle is good and used in [RSA-KEM](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5990). But the devil is in the details, specifically the conditions stated for security in the question:

> the entropy bit string is of the same magnitude as the RSA modulus, or some number such that $m^e\gg n$

Problem is, we do not have a security reduction to the RSA problem from that condition. In RSA-KEM, $m$ is fully random over $[0,n)$, and the symmetric key is derived from $m$. In this way, we have security directly reducible to the RSA problem.

This issue of having no proof is not only theoretical: there would be serious danger if we used the proposed method to transfer a 128-bit uniformly random $m$ encrypted as $c=m^e\bmod n$ by an RSA public key $(n,e)$ with $e=65537$, which matches the stated criteria. There is a theoretical [Meet-in-the-Middle attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2196/555) with cost about $u+v$ modular operations which recovers $m$ if it can be expressed as the product of two integers $u\,v=m$. Ignoring memory costs, a sizable fraction of the keys can be recovered with $2^{67}$ modexps per attacked key. And while the simplest version of that attack requires unrealistically much memory, time vs memory trade-offs may be possible (that's discussed [there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/109034/555)).

Answer (score 1):

NIST SP 800-56B r2 stipulates that for Key Transport, we use KTS-OAEP (Key-Transport Using RSA-OAEP).  RFC 8017 spends few paragraphs on why this specific padding mechanism gives us IND-CCA2 security.  The essence of this security is the probabilistic encryption that the random seed (within the padding scheme) offers, something that textbook RSA does not have.  Even if what you're transporting is not the actual key, but something like a seed or secret from which a cryptographic key is derived, you still want to preserve the secrecy of such value.

Comment: RSA-KEM is actually included in r1 of that document, the reason why it was removed in r2 is unknown to me. There are no problems with RSA-KEM.